# How to validate current password against new password using Yup

Tags: javascript, yup

I am using [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) and [yup-password](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup-password) to validate password creation on my app and ran into a problem when validating New Password against Current Password. I needed to find a way to throw an error if the new password matches the existing one.

I had a bit of a hard time finding this answered anywhere, so I thought I'd create this issue and answer it myself. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Came across [this function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#mixednotoneofarrayofvalues-arrayany-message-string--function) on yup documentation, and here's the implementation:

```
const newPasswordField = () =>
  passwordField().notOneOf(
    [Yup.ref('currentPassword'), null],
    'passwords must be different'
  );
```

When the newPassword matches currentPassword, an error is thrown with the message 'passwords must be different'.